# What does the distribution of Fourier components indicate about the real-space distribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, bayesian

I read a paper that assumes a prior distribution on the Fourier components of a 3D model--specifically that the components are independent and normally distributed:
$$
p(\Theta) = \prod_{l=1}^L \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_l^2} \exp\left(\frac{|V_l|^2}{-2\sigma_l^2}\right)
$$
Where the $V_l$ are 3D Fourier components and $\sigma_l$ are hyper-parameters. As you might expect, the result of using this prior is to "regularize" the model, effectively making it smooth.

My question is, what does this prior indicate about the real spatial process?

**What I have so far**

The only thing I can think of is Bochner's Theorem, which (according to Gaussian Processes in Machine Learning, Rasmussen, page 82) says that in some cases, the spectral density and spatial covariance are Fourier duals of each other. Computing the covariance would be great because then I can write down the spatial process corresponding to the above distribution.

The problems are: 1) I think that only applies in stationary cases and I don't think the distribution above is stationary and 2) I don't know how to go from a *distribution on component values* to a *spectral density*.

Comment: if the discrete Fourier transform is i.i.d. normally distributed, the inverse discrete Fourier transform is an uncorrelated and of constant variance normally distributed random vector. the idea is that this is what we call in signal processing a white noise (no need to be i.i.d, only uncorrelated and identically distributed) and this kind of white noise stays a white noise after any orthonormal change of basis

Comment: @user1952009 could you elaborate? Uncorrelated normal random process sounds like white noise, is that what you mean?

Comment: white noise means i.i.d. and zero-mean process or vector, but in signal processing we often require only zero-mean,  uncorrelated and identically distributed : as I said because this property stays true after any orthonormal change of basis. the (discrete) Fourier transform being such an orthonormal change of basis

Comment: does it answer your question ?

Comment: @user1952009 Makes sense what you said. I'm still confused tough, because in the paper they say the effect of this prior distribution is to smooth the signal in real space. That's because only some of the $\sigma_l$ terms are non-zero. I'd expect that points in real space would have some correlation depending on those values.

Comment: you mean there are considering the Fourier series of some continuous time/space process ?

Comment: @user1952009 Right so this is part of a fitting routine. They are optimizing the Fourier components of an unknown 3D object based on 2D projections. They enforce smoothness using the prior I stated above. I suppose I'm trying to understand what the prior implies about correlation in real space. Here's the paper, equations on p. 410: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283611012290

Comment: sorry can't help you more, or I would have to study the whole paper .... and in my opinion the "smoothness" they talk about depends more  on how $L$ is small, but maybe I'm wrong.